# Why does my program continuously execute when supplying an argument with "<<<"?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, here-document

I have a compiled COTS program (.exe) that I normally interact with via stdin (manual keyboard inputs).  Instead, I'm trying to use the `<<<` to supply input via string instead.

Normally I call the program...

`./program.exe`

Then supply the option I want (in this case, I press "G"), and it performs some actions and outputs some text on the screen.

I'm trying to supply the "G" option from a script by using:

`./program.exe<<<G`

But it seems like the program continuously executes using the "G" option, instead of only executing once.  The output floods my screen and makes my terminal unusable until I forcefully terminate.  Does `<<<` continuously send the string?  I assume the problem is something like the program is expecting to read from stdin and is not designed to handle `<<<`....  but I'm not sure.  Is there some way to make this work?

Comment: The here string should only send it once, this issue is probably related to how your program is handling the input.

Comment: How do you usually exit it? What happens if you start the program normally (without the `<<<`), press G, and then hit Ctrl-D? (I started writing the comment before Gilles's answer came but got distracted. So ignore me if you like, I'm just wondering about how it works)

Comment: @ilkkachu Interesting...  when I start the program, press G, and then hit Ctrl-D it does 1 iteration of output.  If I hold down Ctrl+D it behaves just like when I try to use `<<<`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<<<` does not “continuously send the string”. It sends the string just once. More precisely, it creates a temporary file containing the string, and opens this on the program's standard input.

It seems that this program is buggy and rewinds its input stream when it reaches the end.

To work around this bug, use a pipe to send the input instead of a temporary file. A pipe cannot be rewound, so it won't trigger this particular bug.

```
echo G | ./program.exe
```

Using a pipe may trigger a different bug. Some programs really don't work well when their input isn't coming from a terminal. If a pipe doesn't work, the next step is to use [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) to run the program with an actual terminal (with no user interaction: expect manages the interaction). Expect lets you control what is sent and received on the terminal and when it is sent. Here's an expect script that mimics typing `G` <kbd>Enter</kbd> as soon as the program starts:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ./program.exe
send "G\r"
```

Comment: I tried piping to the program, but it had the same behavior as when I was using `<<<`.

I used expect, and it works great.  Thank you!

Comment: @Dys please remember to accept this answer with the tick mark to show that it best worked for you